# regex for matching programming language like block

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make a small scripting language using c#
currently doing a block parser
im stuck at making regex for block.
Blocks can have ∞ times of sub blocks

**This is what i need to catch**

```
{ 
    naber(); 
}
{
    int x = 5;
    x = 2;
    if (x == 5) {
        x = 5;
    }
}
```

**I tried this but not working**

```
\{[^{}]*|(\{[^\{\}]\})*\}
```

This is my first post please have mercy on me

Comment: Why are you using a regex instead of writing an actual parser with something like [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache)?

Comment: Unfortunately programming languages (at least the types you're trying to make) aren't regular so you can't parse them with regular expressions. At one point or another you'll hit a wall and have to use or write a real parser.

Comment: You can't have one Regex expression for you block.  If you were doing this in Linux I would recommend YACC (Yet Another Compiler Compiler) which uses LEX (similar to REGEX) for expressions.  You expressions are 1) "int x = 5" 2) "x = 2" 3) x == 5 4) x = 5 5) If(  )  A compiler you have to define your language and your expressions.  You can't do both in one structure.

Comment: #Guy Incognito : The expressions are regular.  The OP is missing the language syntax.

Comment: @jdweng "The expressions are regular."? Totally don't get your comment. The Guy's comment seem to be about "regular grammar" vs. "context free grammar" (to my understanding, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/477420.) Not really sure what your comment mean.

Comment: The OP want to build a COMPILER.  Expressions are only a small part of a compiler.

Comment: Well, if `{(?>[^{}]+|(?<o>){|(?<-o>)})*}` solves the issue for your "language", then use it. If the `{` and `}` can appear in any other context than function/method body delimiters, you can't rely on the balanced construct and you will have to write a parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex will not help you for this. If you are designing a scripting language, possibly to be executed, that has blocks and sub-blocks, you need [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) as opposed to [regular grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) which can be expressed through regular expressions.

To interpret a context-free language you need the following steps (simplified):

1. Convert the code string to a list of tokens/symbols. This process is done by a component usually called Lexer.
2. Convert the tokens into a structured tree (AST - Abstract Syntax Tree) based on grammar rules (things like operator precedence, nested code blocks, etc). This is done by a component usually called Parser.
3. From here several options arise, either you translate the AST into native code, or intermediate code (like bytecode) or transpile it into another language; Or you can run it directly in memory, the most simple approach and probably what you want/need.

These should already be plenty of concepts to search for, but all of this can be achieved easily with tools like [ANTLR](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/csharp-target.md). There might be alternatives to ANTLR obviously, I just don’t recall any just now.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with those saying that regex isn't what you should use parsing code.
With that said, it is possible on some reg engines to match characters and get code in a block.

This might work for you `{((?>[^{}]+|(?R))*)}`. If the regex engine supports recursive pattern then it is possible to do some work parsing code.

More here about it [Match balanced curly braces](http://goorep.se:1001/changelog/report/rSelect/PAGE_result.htm?alias=guest&set=&query=Book%20pages&$$TArticleBook1.ArticleBookK=7105&$$TArticle2.ArticleK=9470&link=[[%22B510C1D203054C4D98B0215AAE499B5Ezoom%22,%22TArticleBook1%22,7105]]&hide=4&rows=50&hide=4)